# How to get the Azure DevOps Service Principal ID + Name

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-service-principal

Perhaps my brain is still in bed, but I cannot figure out how to get the name and ID of my Azure DevOps Service Principal. I need to give it permission on a Synapse workspace.

Do I have to create a Azure DevOps Service Principal or is it created automatically once I created a project (and repositories) in Azure DevOps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described above you should create a service connection that will automatically create an application (service principal) on which you can assign IAM privileges.

In order to find the application name/ID you should go under your service connection and press **Manage Service Principal**. Then azure devops will redirect you on Azure on App Registrations/App

[image]

Comment: Ahhh, the name is different from the name of the service connection. That solved it, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

> Do I have to create a Azure DevOps Service Principal or is it created automatically once I created a project (and repositories) in Azure DevOps?

You need to create service principal manually. Here are the detailed steps:

1. Go to "Project Settings" -> "Pipelines/Service connections".
2. Click on "Create a service connection". Choose "Azure resource manager". Scroll down and click on "Next".
3. Select "Service principal (automatic)" (You can select the manual one if you want to manually enter information such as subscription ID and credential). Click on "Next".
4. Select "Subscription" as scope level. If it shows that you do not have an active subscription, please try to do this in InPrivate window. Then fill in the information about service connection name. Click on "Save".

Comment: I checked and there already exists an serviceprincipal (SP) for the subscription in which my Synapse workspace is (Created by the admins). But when I look for the name of the SP in the Synapse workspace's "Access control" window to add a role assignment to this SP, it doesn't find anything under that name.

Comment: I'm trying to follow this article (first step): https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/data-architecture-blog/ci-cd-in-azure-synapse-analytics-part-4-the-release-pipeline/bc-p/2110007